# java application running on tomcat. Unable to access over ajp.

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Application is accessible over tomcat http port.
Application when accessed from web server(Apache http server) gives bad gateway error. 
worker.properties(apache http server) & server.xml(tomcat) are tuned well. Socket/connection timeout is 20 sec on both sides.

Jk.log shows below error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12xjp.png)

The error says tomcat is not accepting any connections. But how come at the same time, application is accessible over http.

On tomcat side I dont see any errors in the log.

Comment: I would like to stick with mod_jk. Please let me know your thoughts how to solve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use different ports for HTTP connection (default is 8080) and for AJP connection (default is 8009). You can check exact values in `conf/server.xml`.

Your error indicates that there are some problems between httpd and client (firewall, slow connection etc.). Try to remove timeouts, like `worker.ajp13.socket_timeout=3`. (https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/common_howto/timeouts.html)

Make sure that ports are not blocked by possible firewalls. For Ubuntu, UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) could be used to open AJP connections: `ufw enable && ufw allow 8009`.

Comment: network & server side doesnt have any issue. 

Sorry I missed to add a point. There are Other applications deployed on the same tomcat. They are accessible. Only a particular application is not accessible.

Comment: Do you mean other applications are accessible with httpd over AJP or they are accessible over Tomcat HTTP port?

Comment: Other applications are accessible with httpd over AJP. As usual all applications are accessible on tomcat http port(8080). NO error at all. Problem is with only one application.. that too on ajp port(8009) only..

Comment: Below are the settings in worker.properties.
worker.ajp13.lbfactor=1
worker.ajp13.socket_timeout=3
worker.ajp13.socket_keepalive=true
worker.ajp13.connection_pool_timeout=3
########################################################

Below are the settings in the server.xml in tomcat.
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"  useBodyEncodingForURI="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
  maxKeepAliveRequests="50"
  connectionTimeout="3000"/>

Comment: Can any body help me here please?

Comment: Add configurations in `httpd.conf`, `workers.properties` and `server.xml` to your post. Try to remove timeouts (check an edited answer).

Comment: I found the root cause.  
@tarashypka Thank you. I did not notice the URL you have given in your suggestion. That info about the timeouts was helpful. 
Below are my findings. 
I am using the default garbage collector in tomcat. While it was taking long pauses during garbage collection, the ajp connection is timing out as per the timeout settings.
Thanks again.. tarashypka